# Flock of Geese alphametic

Tags: no-computers, alphametic

In each of the following **three** alphametic puzzles, every letter stands for a digit in base-10 representation, and different letters stand for different digits. Leading digits are always non-zero.

```
   FLOCK * 6 = GEESE

   FLOCK * 7 = GEESE

   FLOCK * 8 = GEESE
```

Which digit does each letter represent?
(Please present the full analysis how these digits can be determined.)

Comment: Can it be assumed that the F is not zero? Ot should I not rule that out?

Comment: It's not stated if the number value associated with a letter can change between cases. This would make a huge difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **PART 2**

For FLOCK * 7 = GEESE, the answer is:

> F=1, L=0, O=9, C=4, K=8, G=7, E=6, S=3

**Explanation:**

F can only be 1 to maintain the number of digits, therefore, G=7/8/9 and L=0/2/3/4

Since 7 is odd, we can produce numbers with patterns 700#0, 711#1, 722#2, etc. until 988#8.

I started with 700#0. We can establish 70000 and 70070 are divisible by 7. If we keep adding either 70 or 1071 (which is 7 * 53) as needed, we can establish the pattern:

> 70000, 70070, 71141, 72212, 72282, 73353, 74424, 74494, 75565, 76636, 77707, 77777, 78848, 79919, 79989

Finding the next number divisible by 7 with the format 800#0 and continuing the pattern, we get:

> 80010, 80080, 81151, 82222, 82292, 83363, 84434, 85505, 85575, 86646, 87717, 87787, 88858, 89929, 89999

With 900#0, we get

> 90020, 90090, 91161, 92232, 93303, 93373, 94444, 95515, 95585, 96656, 97727, 97797, 98868, 99939

Removing the ones with:

- 1s on any digit,
- repeated tens digit,
- repeated ten-thousands digit,
- 0s formatted 7####,
- 2s formatted 8####, and
- 3s or 4s formatted 9####

We get:

> 72282, 73353, 74424, 74494, 75565, 76636, 78848, 79989, 80080, 82292, 83363, 84434, 85505, 85575, 86646, 89929, 90020, 90090, 95585, 96656, 97727, 98868

I tried dividing it all by 7 and the only working solution is

> 10948 * 7 = 76636

Answer (score 3):

## Partial answer (only first puzzle)

My analysis:
**F is 1** (assuming it can't be 0) because otherwise the result would be 6 digits, in all cases.

For the first case:
GEESE is divisible by 6 which means that it's even, so **E must be an even number**.
GEESE is divisible by 6 which means it's also divisble by 3 which means that the digit sum must be divisible by three which means that **G+S is divisble by three**.
Because G is at least 6 times F then **G is 6 or higher**

Now by these conclusions the possibilities for GEESE is a list that I thought was small enough to check by hand:
60030
60090
62232
62292
64434
64494
68838
68898
70020
70050
70080
72252
72282
74424
74454
74484
76626
76656
76686
78828
78858
80040
80070
82242
82272
84474
86646
86676
90030
90060
92202
92232
92262
94404
94434
94464
96606
96636
98808
98838
98868

So I checked every one of them what they were divided by 6 and if they would fit the equation. My result:

> The solution is $15367 * 6 = 92202$

Comment: In these puzzles I think the first digit can't ever be a 0, so for F=1 this should be alright.

Answer (score 3):

### Part 3

Assuming `F` is at least 1, `FL` must be either `12` or `10` for the product to be less than 10000.

If `FL` is `12`, then `GEESE` is at least 96000. `E` must be even, so it can only be `6` or `8`. If `E` is `6`, then `FLOCK*8` being between 96606 and 96686 requires that `O` is `0` and `C` is `8`. `K` can't be `2`, so it must be `7` to make the units digit correct. But `12087*8=96696` duplicates the digit 9, so `E` being `6` doesn't work. `E` must be `8`, making `O` be `3` and `C` be `5` or `6`. `K` can't be `1`, so it is `6` and `C` is `5`. The result `12356*8=98848` works.

If `FL` is `10`, then `GEESE` is at least 80000 and at most 87999. Again, `E` must be even, so it has to be `2`, `4`, or `6`. If `E` is `2`, then `O` must also be `2`, which is impossible. If `E` is `4`, then `O` must be `5`, and `C` must be `6` to avoid a repeat. Then `GEESE` is either `84484` or `84494`, but neither of these numbers is divisible by 8. Finally, if `E` is `6`, then `O` must be `8`, which is already used as `G`. So none of these cases works.

The only working answer is `12356*8=98848`.